# Check Element Properties with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

How do I check the DOM properties of an element I've selected with Capybara? *(note that this is different from checking attributes)*

Example: I want to see if a checkbox is in the indeterminate state, and I'd like to do something like this:

```
find('input[type="checkbox"]').properties.indeterminate == true
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the best method I have is JavaScript:

```
  def has_indeterminate_field?(text)
    page.evaluate_script "$('label:contains(#{text}) input')[0].indeterminate"
  end
```